# Tcp Listner Variable reuse!! C#

Tags: c#, tcp

I have a Tcp Listner
`TcpListner Listner`
it is running
I want to stop it
and then use it on another IP
how can I do that?
I don't want to create new `TcpListner` variable (C#)

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint is specified in the constructor, so: you will need a second `TcpListener` object. That is unavoidable. You *can* reuse the *variable* that you store the object reference in, but I'm not sure that this is what you mean (I'm pretty sure you're asking about the object, not the variable).

Comment: i am asking about the variable, I want to create new object but I want it to stay ``TcpListner Listner`` and not ``TcpListner Listner1``

Comment: @StackingGrandma then... `Listener?.Stop();` followed by `Listener = new TcpListener(...);` ?